Getting time in a different time zone using C++
C++ will let me get the local time with std::localtime(), but that presents a problem when I'm using an online compiler whose server is in a different continent. How do I get the time in PST instead of "local" time?
Here's the code I'm using:
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  time_t secSinceEpoch = time(0);
  tm* timeStruct = std::localtime(&secSinceEpoch);
  int hour = timeStruct->tm_hour;
  int min = timeStruct->tm_min;

  std::cout << "Time in California is " << hour << ":" << min << std::endl;

  return 0;
}

How to I manipulate localtime() so it returns the time in Los Angeles, rather than in India where the online server is?

Howard has given the correct answer to your question, but... From experience, when dealing with machines in many different locations, it's generally best to use UTC, and let the local user interface code convert this to the local time zone if desired.

Thanks, guys! I hadn't realized that localtime() always returned UTC, so that makes is much simpler. I'll just subtract 7 from the hour.

Subtracting 7 will work great from the second Sunday in March until the first Sunday in November.

@SamuelvanderVeen localtime does not return UTC (except during the winter in the UK). gmtime returns UTC; localtime returns the broken down time, "expressed as local time". What local time really means isn't really defined by the system -- on Unixes, for example, it can be changed by setting the environment variable TZ. (So if you invoke your program with TZ=PST myprog, it should convert to PST, even if the machine is in India.

This can not portably be done in C++ prior to C++20.1
In C++20 it is:
#include <chrono>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::chrono::zoned_time zt{"America/Los_Angeles", std::chrono::system_clock::now()};
  std::cout << "Time in California is " << std::format("{:%H:%M}", zt) << '\n';
}

Demo.
Example output:
Time in California is 13:22

zoned_time is a pairing of a time_zone const* and a system_clock-based time_point.  When formatting it will use the time_zone to translate the sys_time into local_time and format that.  The time_zone can be assigned via an IANA time zone name.
If you instead want the computer's current local time, then simply replace "America/Los_Angeles" with std::chrono::current_zone().

1 Technically that is an exaggeration.  It can be done.  But it is so hard to do that it is not a practical answer to the question.  To do it one has to build a parser to the IANA timezone database and use that to transform system_clock::time_point into any local time in the IANA database.  And then figure out how to format that local time_point.  Here is an example library that did just that:  https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date.  This is the library that became the C++20 solution as described in this answer.
